# Python/Tkinter Permutation How to Skip Empty Fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, permutation

I am currently working on a project that takes in the user's input from a  Tkinter/Python GUI and prints out the permutations.

The user can fill in 6 of the entry fields which spits out the permutations of their inputs. This functionality works perfectly fine.

However, when the user leaves a few entry fields empty, it creates duplicate problems due to the white spaces being permutated upon.

How can I make it so that entry fields that are left empty are to be skipped over and ignored. The output would be the permutations of only the fields with entries... e.g., permutations of 3 words instead of 6, when 3 fields are left blank.

```
from itertools import permutations
from itertools import chain
from tkinter import *
import re

fields = 'Campaign', 'Ad _Group', 'Location', 'Aux_Groups', 'Aux_Groups2', 
'Aux_Groups3'


#makeForm Function
def makeForm(root, fields):
   entries = []

   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=20, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=10, pady=10)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries.append((field, ent))

   return entries


#ExactMatch Function.
def exactMatch(entries):
    words = [entry[1].get() for entry in entries]
    perms = [p for p in permutations((words))]
    x1 = str(perms)
    perms2 = x1.replace("," , '') #Takes out the Quotations
    perms3 = perms2.replace("'" , '') #Takes out the Quotations
    perms4 = perms3.replace("(" , '[')
    perms5 = perms4.replace(')' , ']\n')
    perms6 = perms5.replace (" ", "")


    print("Exact Match:")
    print('------------')
    print(perms6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     root = Tk()
     ents = makeForm(root, fields)
     root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))

     #Exact Match Button
     b2 = Button(root, text='Exact Match', command=(lambda e=ents: exactMatch(e)))
     b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

     #Quit Button
     b6 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
     b6.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

     root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you could fix your comprehension list to accept only *not empty values*, but maybe you want to clean the input words (spaces, symbols...) ? (Also you should update a label in tkinter instead of printing something in a console)

Comment: You could add `.replace(" ", "")` when you get the values from the entries to remove the blank space. (`words = [entry[1].get().replace(" ", "") for entry in entries]`)

Comment: @PRMoureu Thank you for the advice! I left out much of my code, labels, buttons...etc to keep it simple

Comment: @SneakyTurtle That does fix the issue, but my perms are required to be separated by white spaces and nothing else!

Comment: You need to provide a testable code. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated: All code included. Just run python or python3 ./code.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is only going to focus on your main question on how to skip entry fields that are blank or only contain spaces.

We can use `strip()` to remove spaces from either side of a string we get from an entry field.

We can use a `get()`, `strip()` and an if statement to check if the new value is not "" and then continue.

```
for entry in self.entry_list:
            x = entry.get().strip()
            if x != "":
                self.perm_list.append(x)
```

Take a look at the below code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import permutations

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master

        self.entry_list = []
        self.perm_list = []

        for i in range(5):
            self.entry_list.append(tk.Entry(self.master))
            self.entry_list[i].pack()

        tk.Button(self.master, text="Perm", command = self.begin_perm).pack()


    def begin_perm(self):
        self.perm_list = []
        for entry in self.entry_list:
            x = entry.get().strip()
            if x != "":
                self.perm_list.append(x)

        x = [p for p in permutations(self.perm_list)]
        print(x)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() 
    MyApp = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

```
[('Time', 'Apple', 'Car'), ('Time', 'Car', 'Apple'), ('Apple', 'Time', 'Car'), ('Apple', 'Car', 'Time'), ('Car', 'Time', 'Apple'), ('Car', 'Apple', 'Time')]
```